# Putting labels to itemize makes beamer slide overflow on right margin

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin {frame}{Upper gastro-intestinal endoscopy }
\begin{itemize}
        \item[Esophagus] Four columns of grade IV  esophageal varices were noted. Red colored signs present 
        \item [Stomach] Fundus of stomach showed altered blood. Body and antropyloric area of stomach was normal
        \item [Duodenum] Normal 
        \item [procedure] Endoscopic variceal ligation done 
\end{itemize}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Why the beamer slide fails to adjust the text properly  in this code? The text overflows on left margin. 
Kindly suggest

Answer (score 2):

`itemize` is really intended for bullets of various sorts, `description` adjusts better to large labels:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin {frame}{Upper gastro-intestinal endoscopy }
\begin{description}
        \item[Esophagus] Four columns of grade IV  esophageal varices were noted. Red colored signs present 
        \item [Stomach] Fundus of stomach showed altered blood. Body and antropyloric area of stomach was normal
        \item [Duodenum] Normal 
        \item [procedure] Endoscopic variceal ligation done 
\end{description}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In beamer, alignment of description is poor. If I use enumitem package, it will conflict with innertheme, removing all bullets from lists.

Comment: @Vaibhav define "poor" it seems to be better than itemize here? Would you prefer the result from `\addtolength\leftmargini{2cm}
\begin{itemize}` ?